# Que botón fue presionado, si se genera dentro de un for

Tags: php, laravel, formularios, botón, blade

Hola estoy trabajando con laravel: desde mi controlador envió un arreglo con la información de varias opciones a elegir (solo puede elegir una), este es un ejemplo del arreglo:

```
^ array:3 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "paqueteria" => "ESTAFETA"
    "servicio" => "ESTAFETA_NEXT_DAY"
    "precio" => 287.68
    "dias" => 2
    "cobertura" => "NORMAL"
    "id" => 4
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "paqueteria" => "PAQUETEXPRESS"
    "servicio" => "STANDARD"
    "precio" => 270.28
    "dias" => 5
    "cobertura" => "NORMAL"
    "id" => 8
  ]
  2 => array:6 [▼
    "paqueteria" => "ESTAFETA"
    "servicio" => "ESTAFETA_STANDARD"
    "precio" => 269.12
    "dias" => 5
    "cobertura" => "NORMAL"
        "id" => 5
      ]
]
```

lo muestro en la vista en una tabla con un for:

```
    @for($i=0; $i<$go_c; $i++)
        <tr>
          <th>{{$go2[$i]["paqueteria"]}}</th>
          <td>{{$go2[$i]["servicio"]}}</td>
          <td>{{$go2[$i]["precio" ]}}</td>
          <td>{{$go2[$i]["dias"]}}</td>
          <td>{{$go2[$i]["cobertura"]}}</td>
          <td><button type="input" class="btn btn-dark">Comprar</button></td>   
        </tr>
      <input type="hidden" name="datos" value= {{$go2[$i]["id"]}}>
      <input type="hidden" name="temp" value={{$temp}} >
   @endfor
```

una vez que el usuario elige el servicio que quiere ocupar, yo necesito saber cual a elegido, lo intente mediante el **hidden 'datos**' pero obviamente se queda con el ultimo valor que le asigno el for, como puedo saber el id del servicio que esta seleccionando?

el numero de servicios siempre varia, no quiero/puedo enviar un arreglo para cada servicio y hacer cada despliegue del servicio por separado.

Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Sería más simple si usaras un `select ... option` en vez de un `table ... tr ... td`. Dicho eso, convendría implementar Ajax o la API Fetch de JavaScript para comunicar entre cliente y servidor.

Comment: No se entiende cómo haría un usuario para seleccionar algo, ya que sólo muestras datos y el input está oculto.

Comment: La manera en como muestras los datos y la forma en como quieres recuperar la seleccion del usuario no seria la correcta, ya que puedes usar un select el cual seria mas sencillo, pero si eso no te sirve puedes usar un checkbox con un value y alli saber cual escogio, ahora si buscas algo mas avanzado, como por ejemplo 100 registros, puedes usar datatable